# How do I group on ordered rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have below table in postgres

```
| col1 | col2                |
|:----:|---------------------|
| A    | 2018-02-21 01:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-21 13:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-21 14:00:01 |
| B    | 2018-02-21 16:00:01 |
| B    | 2018-02-22 06:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-22 10:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-23 11:00:01 |
| C    | 2018-02-24 15:00:01 |
```

I want output like this

```
| col1 | col2                |
|:----:|---------------------|
| A    | 2018-02-21 01:00:01 |
| B    | 2018-02-21 16:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-22 10:00:01 |
| C    | 2018-02-24 15:00:01 |
```

How can I achieve this output?

Comment: Redshift and Postgres are two very different products. Which one **are** you using?

Comment: Query patterns are almost similar. Have to run on both platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `lag` to get the previous col1 value and comparing it with the current row's value.

```
select col1,col2
from (select col1,col2,lag(col1) over(order by col2) as prev_col1
      from tbl
     ) t
where prev_col1 is null or prev_col1<>col1
```